# BASH Curl - "bash: !: event not found"

Tags: bash, curl

I have a curl command as follows which can contain a password. The password can contain special characters. !£$%^&#-~@ etc.

```
curl d "valuea=1234&password=1234@!&valuec=87979&submit=Set" -XPOST "http://$ipa/school.cgi"
```

When this is run I get:    `bash: !: event not found`

How do I escape the special characters in the URL string ?

Thanks

Comment: See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Comment: Thanks that makes sense to use the single quotes. But how do I have use a variable in the URL ? eg: `curl d 'valuea=1234&password=$password&valuec=87979&submit=Set'` ?